# How the next line of code executed only after the first line of code execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

On success of my form i called a function called "onReSuccessFunction()".In that function i had a form submit code.But before complete the form submit the next line of code get executed and redirected to another page .Hence the functionality  of first checking is not working.Do anyone have an idea for solving this issue?

Code

```
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm("ActionEvent", "Energy", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onReSuccessFunction", HttpMethod = "post",async ="false"}, new { id = "frmEnergy", enctype = "multipart/form-data", target = "ifrReFileUpload" }))
{
    @Html.Partial("../Energy/_CreateOrEdit", Model)
}

function onReSuccessFunction(result) {

    if (chekHaveAnyFileUpload("#divReUploadDocument")) {
         document.getElementById("frmEnergy").submit(); 
    }
    if (result.Energy.TransStatus == "2") {
         if (moveToNextTab(1) == false) { 
            window.location.href = "../../folio/Index"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the first one is `true`, will the second one be `false`?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to end your function after submitted the code just use `return;` or use `else if`

```
function onReSuccessFunction(result) {
    if (chekHaveAnyFileUpload("#divReUploadDocument")) {
        document.getElementById("frmEnergy").submit(); 
     }
    else if (result.Energy.TransStatus == "2") {
        if (moveToNextTab(1) == false) { window.location.href = "../../folio/Index"; }
    }
}
```